# Merging Data frames and creating columns based on conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

I have 2 data frames

Data Frame A:

```
Time Reading
1      20 
2      23
3      25
4      22
5      24
6      23 
7      24
8      23
9      23
10     22
```

Data Frame B:

```
TimeStart TimeEnd Alarm
 2            5     556
 7            9     556
```

I would like to create the following joined dataframe:

```
Time Reading Alarmtime Alarm alarmno 
 1    20        n/a     n/a    n/a
 2    23         2      556     1
 3    25                556     1
 4    22                556     1 
 5    24         5      556     1
 6    23         n/a    n/a     n/a
 7    24         7      556     2
 8    23                556     2
 9    23         9      556     2
 10   22         n/a    n/a     n/a
```

I can do the join easy enough however im struggling with getting the following rows filled with the alarm until the time the alarm ended. Also numbering each individual alarm so even if they are the same alarm they are counted separately. Any thoughts on how i can do this would be great

Thanks

Comment: You can do non-equi joins in `data.table` using your data frames directly. If you want to use `dplyr` the best solution is probably to expand data frame B so it has a for every time.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(sqldf)

df_b$AlarmNo <- seq_len(nrow(df_b))

sqldf('
select  a.Time
        , a.Reading
        , case  when a.Time in (b.TimeStart, b.TimeEnd)
                  then a.Time
                else NULL
        end as AlarmTime
        , b.Alarm
        , b.AlarmNo
from    df_a a
        left join df_b b
          on a.Time between b.TimeStart and b.TimeEnd
')

#    Time Reading AlarmTime Alarm AlarmNo
# 1     1      20        NA    NA      NA
# 2     2      23         2   556       1
# 3     3      25        NA   556       1
# 4     4      22        NA   556       1
# 5     5      24         5   556       1
# 6     6      23        NA    NA      NA
# 7     7      24         7   556       2
# 8     8      23        NA   556       2
# 9     9      23         9   556       2
# 10   10      22        NA    NA      NA
```

Or

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df_b)

df_c <- 
  df_b[, .(Time = seq(TimeStart, TimeEnd), Alarm, AlarmNo = .GRP)
       , by = TimeStart]

merge(df_a, df_c, by = 'Time', all.x = T)

#     Time Reading TimeStart Alarm AlarmNo
#  1:    1      20        NA    NA      NA
#  2:    2      23         2   556       1
#  3:    3      25         2   556       1
#  4:    4      22         2   556       1
#  5:    5      24         2   556       1
#  6:    6      23        NA    NA      NA
#  7:    7      24         7   556       2
#  8:    8      23         7   556       2
#  9:    9      23         7   556       2
# 10:   10      22        NA    NA      NA
```

Data used:

```
df_a <- fread('
Time Reading
1      20 
2      23
3      25
4      22
5      24
6      23 
7      24
8      23
9      23
10     22
')

df_b <- fread('
TimeStart TimeEnd Alarm
 2            5     556
 7            9     556
')
```